# How can I make background of div element transparent, where there's element on top?

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
    body {
        color: white;
        background-image: url("https://www.icecraftstudio.repl.co/sprites/images/blue_ice.png");
        background-repeat: repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: 10%
    }

    #content {
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.85);
    }

    .group {
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 10px;
        border: 4px double rgb(0, 77, 177);
        background-color: rgb(0, 21, 80);
    }

    article {
        background: transparent;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <h1>Page</h1>
            <div class="group">
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <article>
                    <h3>Article 1</h3>
                    <p>Some text</p>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <h3>Article 2</h3>
                    <p>Some text</p>
                </article>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I need to make the background of the *div* with *content* id to be visible as background of *article* elements. However the background of the *group* class *div* is visible instead. Is there any way to make it how I want it?

Answer (score 2):

Set its `background-color` property to `transparent`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
    body {
        color: white;
        background-image: url("https://www.icecraftstudio.repl.co/sprites/images/blue_ice.png");
        background-repeat: repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: 10%
    }

    #content {
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    .group {
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 10px;
        border: 4px double rgb(0, 77, 177);
        background-color: rgb(0, 21, 80);
    }

    article {
        background: transparent;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <h1>Page</h1>
            <div class="group">
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <article>
                    <h3>Article 1</h3>
                    <p>Some text</p>
                </article>
                <article>
                    <h3>Article 2</h3>
                    <p>Some text</p>
                </article>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry but I mean, that the elements *article* should have the black semi transparent background with the ice in background in their actual background, so that the dark blue one is "skipped" behind the *article* elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can move the background-image property from the "**body**" element to "**.article**", and for the dark overlay, you can use pseudo-elements for that like below :

```
.article {
    background-image: url("https://www.icecraftstudio.repl.co/sprites/images/blue_ice.png");
    position: relative;
}

.article::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -99;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0, 21, 80);
}
```

and with that done, you should have the ice background in each article with the dark overlay, and the body will remain transparent.

If this is not the result you are looking for, please consider adding more details so we can understand the problem more.

Comment: Thank you for your help, however because the background of the body is actually fixed in the full code of the website, it would look better if simply the actually body was visible as background of the article.